# SQL: How do I tag rows based on like values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatable, logic, business-intelligence

I have a SQl table that looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to figure out how to tag a set of Groups with a Primary attribute based on the domain a group is in and that they all have the same SetID.

For instance, I want to tag a Group as the Primary of a set when it is in Domain A. So in the table above row 2 would be tagged as a Primary just as row 6 would be tagged as Primary.

I am currently using SQl Server. Please help!

Thank you:)

**EDIT**

My desired output is something like this: 
[image]

So out of the groups that are in SetID 1, row 2 is in Domain A so that one becomes primary. Essentially what I am doing is identifying sets of groups that are to be consolidated. So the Primary tag allows me to determine which group will be the parent and which others in a set will be its children.

Comment: Please edit your question and show your desired output.  I understand the logic, but not what the tag actually looks like.  Remember, the row number is not stored in the table, unless you have an explicit column that stores it.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you want the tag on *all* the rows in the set.  The only logic thing for the tag is the account name column.  So, something like this should work:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             min(case when domain = 'A' then AccountName end) over (partition by setid) as minan
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set primary = minan;
```

EDIT:

For the clarified question, you should be able to do:

```
update table t
    set primary = 'primary'
    where domain = 'A';
```

However, you would be better off with a computed column, in my opinion in this case.

If there could be multiple rows with domain A for a set, then:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by domain order by newid()) as seqnum
      from table t
     )
update toupdate
    set primary = 'primary'
    where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I only want to tag on 1 row in a set. If I inner join the table on itself where SetID is equal and Domain = A to set Primary work?